# Scroll header fixed jquery code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Scroll from top header fix not working.

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 350) {
      $('.header-nav').addClass('fixed2');
    } else {
      $('.header-nav').removeClass('fixed2');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.fixed2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

html {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-nav">
  <ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register Your Business</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery code not conflicting, I used `$` to jQuery.

jQuery not working.

Comment: what you actually want to do here with scroll?

Comment: Be more specific than '_not working_'.Can you provide a working fiddle for the issue.

Comment: Did you check your console for errors?

Comment: Please put the "fiddle" in the question as a [mcve] (do not use a link).

Comment: after scroll up 350px my header(containing menu) should be fixed i have run this code many times before it works fine but this time not.

Comment: It's working, what do you mean by not working ??

Comment: The code is working as expected , after scrolling 350px the header becomes fixed and visible at the top of the screen and remains the same on scrolling down further. When you scroll up, the class `fixed2` is removed and header's position is reverted back to `static`, i.e. now it follows the normal flow of the page and becomes visible only after you scroll to the top end of the page where it actually existed prior to the position change.

Comment: I know this code is running.. i used this code before many time.. but now not working may be jquery conflict but i tried conflict code

Comment: i dont know how

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console. Have you tried debugging inside the scroll function ?

Comment: Yes Appear
1st= Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2nd= Uncaught TypeError: $(...).champ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: Do check it out . It has to be the second one that is causing the issue.

Comment: @inderjeet: have you checked my answer?

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar i checked your answer..its working. my code also working but some html page not running jquery code...i dont know how..i use my own code (which i posted above) many time its working but this time not working....

Answer (score -1):

This code will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('.header-nav').addClass('fixed2');
                $('.header-nav').css('top', Math.round($(this).scrollTop()) + 'px');
            } else {
                $('.header-nav').removeClass('fixed2');
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.fixed2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
   

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <div class="header-nav">
        <ul id="main-nav">

            <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">  Register Your Busi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div style="height:1000px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: What did you change, what is it doing differently?

Comment: You can see i have changed position fixed to absolute and setting top position of menu when scroll